# Does NSStringFromClass return the identifier?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a cell in Xcode storyboard with an identifier and class set in the properties.

In the code I'm looking at in someone's GitHub repository that does something similar to my app, it has:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NSStringFromClass(myCellClass), forIndexPath: indexPath) as myCellClass
```

Documentation says "Returns the name of a class as a string."

So can I replace `NSStringFromClass(myCellClass)` with `"myidentifier"` that I set in the storyboard properties?

The error I'm getting, although it may be irrelevant is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier MyApp.myCellClass - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Comment: Did you read the error message??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
    NSStringFromClass(myCellClass), 
    forIndexPath: indexPath) as myCellClass
```

Interesting idea. But that code works only because that programmer has manually entered the name of the cell class as the cell identifier in the storyboard. The two things have, inherently, nothing whatever to do with each other.

Comment: Thank-you. Here's the actual implementation is here on line 164 and 171-172: https://github.com/acani/Chats/blob/master/Chats/Chats/ChatViewController.swift

Comment: Okay but I believe I've answered the question. You can't pass `NSStringFromClass(myCellClass)` at that point unless that class name _is_ also the identifier. But it probably isn't.

Comment: Any ideas why my version that instead uses a string, calls the constructor `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and his version calls the other constructor: `override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)`

Comment: Do not leech. If you have a new question, ask a new question.